# Working with Greenlet values

Tags: python, asynchronous, concurrency, gevent, greenlets

I would like to implement an async work into one of my testing functions.
The function, **heuristically**, looks like this -

```
def test_sessions(self):
    sessions = []
    """
    Creating 10k session instances
    """
    for i in xrange(10000):
        sessions.append(Session.create_session(session_handle, login_params(user, pass))
    """
    Foreach session instance, check session validity by running read_dir command
    """
    for session in sessions:
        connection = Connection.create_connection(addrs, port)
        connection.session = session.id
        response = connection.read_dir(dir)
    """
    Deleting the 10k opened sessions
    """
    for session in sessions:
        session.delete(session_handle)
```

The time that takes to perform this check for 10k sessions is around 30m. Hence, I though to use greenlet and gevent for these sections (create, check and delete) in order to speed things up a bit.

I'm having some trouble understanding how to implement this idea since I couldn't figure how to access the session instances that will be created by the greenlet threads.. I couldn't find any good example of how to be able to use the greenlet values.

Please direct me to the right way of using greenlet here

Answer (score 1):

Put the code for a single session into a single function, something like this:

```
def check_session()
    session = Session.create_session(session_handle, login_params(user, pass)
    connection = Connection.create_connection(addrs, port)
    connection.session = session.id
    response = connection.read_dir(dir)
    session.delete(session_handle)
```

Now you should import greenlet, monkey-patch all, and then create tasks using
    tasks = [ Greenlet.spawn(check_session) for i in range(10000) ]
    for task in tasks:
        task.run()

All the tasks will be started. Note that greenlets don't run in parallel - they only block on input/output such as network sockets, whereupon another will start executing. If most of your time is spent waiting for network, they should speed things up a lot. If not, not.

Also be careful if you are using some very specific or custom code for accessing the network. `monkey.patch_all()` replaces the Python socket code (and disk i/o, etc.) with a gevent version which yields to another greenlet instead of waiting. If your code doesn't use `socket`, it might not be patched and it will work sequentially as usual.